# I am trying to use for loop to compare if any values in a dataframe is equal to the values in another vector

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains what illnesses patients have. Each of the disease is represented by a number. Besides, there is also a column containing the values of disease that I want to check for. From here, I would like to use for loop to iterate each of the value in that column and compare it with the values in the dataframe to generate a column of 1 & 0 (1 for having the disease, and 0 for not having).

[image: The dataframe containing the diseases patients have]

[image: The values for the diseases that I want to check for]

So far, I have tried using the following code and it did not do anything I want.

```
for(i in sample$disease){
  for(j in patient_illness){
  name<- paste("icd", i, sep="")
    assign(
      name, ifelse(
        any(j==i, na.rm=T), 1, 0
          )
        )
      }}
```

Comment: (1) Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly. (2) It's not clear what your expected output is. (3) I suspect that `%in%` will be relevant once you provide usable data and clear expected output.

Comment: I am sorry about the inconvenience that I may have caused. I am a new user here and have no idea how to properly show my tibble here. Sorry.

Comment: It's not a problem for me, but it can really diminish your chances of getting a quality answer (or one at all). It helps you do reduce the "cost" of us trying to work with your code and data, and anytime you assume that either (a) we will know just by looking at an image of data, or (b) we are willing to transcribe data from an "eye chart" image like that, your chances go down. To me it isn't about being discourteous to us, it's about maximizing your likelihood. Hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

Lacking real data, I'll mimic your efforts with `mtcars`.

```r
disease <- c(4, 6)
+sapply(mtcars, `%in%`, disease)
#       mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
#  [1,]   0   1    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    1    1
#  [2,]   0   1    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    1    1
#  [3,]   0   1    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    1    0
#  [4,]   0   1    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    0
#  [5,]   0   0    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    0
#  [6,]   0   1    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    0
#  [7,]   0   0    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    1
#  [8,]   0   1    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    1    0
#  [9,]   0   1    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    1    0
# [10,]   0   1    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    1    1
# [11,]   0   1    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    1    1
# [12,]   0   0    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    0
# [13,]   0   0    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    0
# [14,]   0   0    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    0
# [15,]   0   0    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    1
# [16,]   0   0    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    1
# [17,]   0   0    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    1
# [18,]   0   1    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    1    0
# [19,]   0   1    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    1    0
# [20,]   0   1    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    1    0
# [21,]   0   1    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    0
# [22,]   0   0    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    0
# [23,]   0   0    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    0
# [24,]   0   0    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    1
# [25,]   0   0    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    0
# [26,]   0   1    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    1    0
# [27,]   0   1    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    0
# [28,]   0   1    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    0
# [29,]   0   0    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    1
# [30,]   0   1    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    1
# [31,]   0   0    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    0
# [32,]   0   1    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    1    0
```

This is a `matrix`; if you need a frame, just wrap with `data.frame(+(sapply(...)))`.

The main effort here is accomplished using `` `%in%` ``, which checks for set-membership.

```r
disease <- c(4, 6)
1:10 %in% disease
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

From there, you said you wanted 1s and 0s, so I use the shortcut of `+(.)` which implicitly coerces the data from `logical` to `integer`.

```r
+(1:10 %in% disease)
#  [1] 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
```